# Android.Gradle: Autoincrement versionCode/versionName before create distributive

Tags: android, gradle

Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 4.2

My **app/build.gradle** snippet:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2.3"
}
```

My steps to create **release** distributive (apk):

1. Increment versionCode and versionName
2. Run, from console, command: `gradlew assembleRelease`

OK. It's work.

But I do not want manually increment **versionCode**/**versionName** before create distributive.

Is it possible to automate it? Or I need to write custom Gradle task?

Comment: No auto increment procedure. Only thing you can do is keep it in strings.xml to keep unique reference if you have some other feature like showing app version in app